# How to control, reset, or edit environment variables in vscode on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm working on an application in vscode whose behavior is impacted by the settings of a handful of specific environment variables (the three "proxy" variables).  I'm doing this on an Ubuntu VM.

At one point I realized that I had to change the settings (clear them) in order for my application to work.  I know that it can be challenging to change env vars in subprocesses, so I decided to keep it simple and simply restart the entire VM after I changed my .profile.  After the restart, I checked a shell window and the vars were set as I wanted (not set).  I then started up vscode from my Ubuntu favorites bar.  In the terminal window I printed the values of those vars.  They still had the values I set before.  I verified that when I ran the application from vscode (not from the terminal window in vscode), it behaved badly, so it was using the old values.  In the terminal window, I then manually cleared those variables to put them into the correct state. I manually ran the service from the terminal window, and it did what it was supposed so, reflecting the cleared variables.

It appears that vscode is storing environment settings on disk and never getting them from the parent shell again.

How do I control this behavior?

Comment: what if you start VSC from the command line, NOT the favorites bar. You don't need to restart the VM when you change your profile, just create a new terminal and start VSC from there

Comment: That made no effective difference.  When I print the env vars in the embedded terminal, it shows the values I want (none), but when I run the application from vscode, it still has the old values. If I instead run the application from the embedded terminal, it has the good values.

Comment: VSC is running the application by typing a command in a terminal, so how can they have different environments, or have you set the vars in your launch config

Comment: there is a difference, the vars are now gone in the VSC terminal

Comment: Well, I guess I figured this out.  I found the "settings.json" file that had the proxy variable set.  I don't remember if I added that manually or not.  I removed that, and now it's working as expected.